# Can I say: Not so homeless a black cat?

Tags: grammar

I know that grammatically correct is 'How sad a story!', but can I put an indefinite article before adjective 'black' e.g. 'Not so homeless a black cat'?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Grammatically it’s fine, but its meaning will depend on the context. It’s like Winston Churchill’s “Some chicken! Some neck!”  Google it and you’ll see what I mean. Grammar is like the plumbing and wiring of a house. Vitally important, and subject to many physical rules, but we arrange these things to suit the walls and doors that define the space we live in.

Comment: "Not so fat a man". Not so stupid a question. Yes, but not so often as not.

Comment: What does "Not so homeless a black cat" actually mean? I'm puzzled. You seem to have chosen a difficult example, perhaps because "homeless" is not normally a gradable adjective. A cat is either homeless or it isn't. "Not so beautiful a black cat" works better. But one would only use this if the focus of attention was on black cats specifically - and not cats in general.

Comment: It contravenes the non-gradability of absolute adjectives rule, and so some would say it's unacceptable. But the rule itself isn't absolute, with broadening for emphasis (eg 'quite dead'), inflationary usage ('a bit full') or humour ('this parrot is somewhat late'). // 'Not so homeless a black cat!': in wry writing, fine.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth But I'm still trying to fit "...not so homeless a black cat" into a complete sentence and accompanying dialogue.  "That black cat is homeless. Another one, a not so homeless a black cat was here last week".  That's about the best I can do. But it is tortured syntax to my ear.

Comment: @WS2 - Or: He was not so homeless a black cat that he didn’t have anywhere to go when the rain started coming down in torrents.

Comment: @WS2 Bob: "That's a wretched looking black cat." Jill: "The poor thing probably has no home. It'd be different if he were a fluffy white kitten." Tom: "He's the duchess's; he lives over at Talksworth House."  Bob: "Hmm. Not _so_ homeless a black cat."

Comment: @Jim Very good.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth A creditable attempt. Far better than I could do. But Jim edges it.

Answer (score 1):

No, it isn't correct. But you could say:

> a not-so-homeless black cat.

This would be understood that you are referring to a black cat that is evidently not homeless. It uses 'not-so-homeless' as a compound adjective. The hyphens are necessary to group this phrase together as an adjective.

However, it wouldn't really work as an exclamation like in your example of "how sad a story", which is not really comparable. There are gradations of 'how sad' something may be. Saying "*how sad a story!*" or "*what a sad story!*" is really like saying "*that is a **very** sad story!*". There are no gradations of homelessness - one is either homeless or not. You could say "*what a scruffy-looking cat!*", because it could be *very* scruffy, or *slightly* scruffy.

Comment: You could also say "**Not such a** homeless black cat [after all].”

Comment: @Mari-LouA you could, although that is sarcastic rather than at face value. Repeating the point in my answer, there are not really gradations of homelessness. Saying "not such a homeless cat" would be a passive way of saying "the cat is not homeless", contrary to claims it was.

Comment: I was pointing out how the indefinite article could precede the noun phrase "homeless black cat" and still keep "not". How someone *says* a phrase can make the difference between sarcasm and simply stating a fact. The same observation could be made for "a not-so-homeless black cat." it all depends on context and intonation.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I think my construction is more likely to be used in a comparison.

Comment: I agreed with your answer and upvoted, I offered another alternative. I'm not saying mine is right and yours is wrong.